# Largest number that divides $n^2(n^2 - 1)(n^2 - n - 2)$ for all $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Obtain the greatest natural that divides $n^2(n^2 - 1)(n^2 - n - 2)$ for all natural numbers $n$.

What should be the approach in these type of questions?

Should I equate with prime factorization $2^a 3^b 5^c \cdots$ etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

\begin{align}
f(n) & = n^2(n^2-1)(n^2-n-2)\\
& = n^2(n+1)(n-1)(n+1)(n-2)\\
& = n^2(n+1)^2(n-1)(n-2)
\end{align}
$n=3$ gives us $9 \times 16 \times 2 = 288$. So the natural number dividing $n^2(n+1)^2(n-1)(n-2)$ for all $n$ should be a divisor of $288$.

Also, note that $24$ has to divide $n^2(n+1)^2(n-1)(n-2)$ since $24$ divides $(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)$ since it is a product of $4$ consecutive integers.

Further, $2$ divides $n(n+1)$. Hence, we know that at-least $48$ divides $f(n)$. Hence, the desired number should be a multiple of $48$ and must divide $288$.

Can you finish it from here by looking at $f(n)$ for couple of other values?
Move the mouse over the gray area for the answer.

> Since the largest number must be a multiple of $48$ and must divide $288$. The possible options are $$\{48, 96, 144, 288\}$$
>  $$\text{$f(4) = 2400$. And $144,288$ doesn't divide $2400$. Hence, the largest number cannot be $144$ or $288$.}$$
>  $$\text{$f(5) = 10,800$. And $96$ doesn't divide $10,800$. Hence, the largest number cannot be $96$. Hence, the largest number is $48$.}$$

Comment: What you did in this gray area (Move the mouse...) is great. How do you do that? :)

Comment: @BabakSorouh You need to do `>!` before the text you want to hide.

Answer (score 2):

By below, $\,2^{4}\!\cdot\! 3\,$ is the largest integer dividing all $\rm\:f(n).\:$ No higher power of $2$ or $3$ divides all $\rm\,f(n)\,$ by the value of $\rm\,f(13),$ and no prime $\rm\,p\ge 5\,$ divides all $\rm\,f(n)\,$ by the value of $\rm\,f(p\!+\!3).$ $\quad$ 
$$\quad\begin{eqnarray}\rm 2^4\cdot 3\:|\: f(n) &=&\rm\ \ \color{#C00}{(n\!+\!1)\ n}\ \ (n\!+\!1)n(n\!-\!1)(n\!-\!2)\\ &=&\rm\ \color{#C00}{2{n+1\choose 2}}\, 24{n+1\choose 4}\\ 
\rm 2^{ 5},\,3^2\nmid\, f(13) &=&\rm\ 14^{\!\ 2}\ 13^{\!\ 2}\ 12\ \ 11 =\, 2^{ 4}\ 3\,\cdots\\
\rm prime\,\ p\nmid f(p\!+\!3) &=&\ \rm (p\!+\!4)^2 (p\!+\!3)^2 (p\!+\!2) (p\!+\!1)\ \ if\ \ p\ge 5
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: I think readers could use a little more words, Bill. Just a constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0):

Factor as $(n-2)(n-1)n^2(n+1)^2$.  It is easy to see that no prime greater than $3$ **must** divide this product.  (For if $p$ is a prime greater than $3$, let $n-3=p$.)

Our product is obviously divisible by $3$. By choosing $n-1=3$, we can make sure that $3^2$ does not divide our product.

To minimize the power of $2$ that divides our product, we make $n-2$ (respectively, $n-1$) divisible by $4$ but not by $8$. Then $n^2$ (respectively, $(n+1)^2$) is divisible by $4$ but not by $8$. Thus $2^4$ must divide our product, and a higher power of $2$ need not.

We conclude that the largest positive integer that always divides our product is $(3^1)(2^4)$.